# Spacial data for region mapping

Tags: r, maps, rstudio

I have some data in the UK and I need to introduce a map of all 9 regions of England. I tried using library(maps) but the plots I get do not have any regional information and I just end up with the whole of the United Kingdom.

Ideally i am looking for a result like this
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b4/English_regions_2009.svg/370px-English_regions_2009.svg.png

(I cant actually attach pictures due to the *lack* of reputation points,apologies!)

My data has a column for regions with character values:

```
         EastMid
         EastEng 
         London
         NorthEast 
         NorthWest 
         SouthEast 
         SouthWest
         WestMid 
         Yorkshire
```

I would then go on to map by color regions with different attributes

How would I go on about this?

Comment: Probably your best bet is going to be to find shapefiles with the region breakouts already created, which you can then map your values to. A quick googlin' for 'uk shapefile' gives a range of possible sources, among them this post on SE: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154540/where-can-i-find-spatial-data-for-uk-administrative-boundaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as Andrew wrote you need to find and download shapefiles with necessary regions. Such split as you need is usually called historical regions or standard statistical regions. You might want to check this site: http://www.natureonthemap.naturalengland.org.uk/

Second, you read shapefile and merge with referendum data. Make sure that region names at the referendum file are exactly the same as in geospatial file (I use file downloaded from the site mentioned above, if you download another shapefile the names probably will be different):

```
library(rgdal)    
library(tmap)
geoEN = readOGR(".", "maghistengland")
```

In this case region names are stored in NAME (in another shapefile attribute name can be different). You can check what information consists of geospatial file by:

```
ogrInfo(".", "maghistengland")
```

For the purpose of the example I am creating fake figures of voting results.

```
votes = as.data.frame(
    cbind(
    c("EAST MIDLANDS",
    "EAST OF ENGLAND",
    "LONDON",
    "NORTH EAST",
    "NORTH WEST",
    "SOUTH EAST",
    "WEST MIDLANDS",
    "YORKSHIRE AND THE HUMBER",
    "SOUTH WEST"),
    c(60, 65, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 30),
    c(40, 35, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 70)
  ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

names(votes) = c("Regions", "Yes", "No")

votes$Yes = as.numeric(votes$Yes)
votes$No = as.numeric(votes$No)
votes$Result = colnames(votes)[max.col(votes[,2:3])+1]
```

Now we can merge both files:

```
mapEN = append_data(geoEN, votes, key.shp = "NAME", key.data = "Regions")
```

Third, create necessary charts. Here are three examples. You can play with number of groups (n = 2, 3, 4..), colors etc.

```
tm_shape(mapEN) +
    tm_fill("Yes", title = "This is a title", palette = "Blues", n=4) +
    tm_borders(alpha=.5)

tm_shape(mapEN) +
    tm_fill("No", title = "This is a title", palette = "Reds", n=5) +
    tm_borders(alpha=.5)

tm_shape(mapEN) +
    tm_fill("Result", palette = c("Red", "Blue")) +
    tm_borders(alpha=.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer! Greatly appreciated